# Funny alignment in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, text-formatting

This is driving me crazy.
I have searched the web for an answer, without success.
All results are simple pointers on how to use the formatting on the sheets.
This misalignment seems to be something Google Sheets just decided to do on its own.

I have a spreadsheet with some numerical data and some cells with values which are functions of other cells.

The inputs are horizontally centred, and the outputs are right-justified.
But **some** of these output cells have a small right margin, and I cannot make it go away or figure out what causes it.

If I specify right-justified, they shift a little to the left (red cells)
If I specify centred, they misalign, but by less. (green cells)
If I specify left-justified, they line up. (blue cells)

DETAILS FOLLOW:

Description of cells:
C10 through I29 are the inputs (not all are filled in).

(Red) B32 =sum(C10:I10,C21:I21,C29) --> Has margin
(Red) D32 =AVERAGE(C10:I10,C21:I21,C29:D29) --> Has margin
(Blk) D34 =average(C21:I21) --> Has no margin
(Blk) other nearby cells also --> no margins

Interesting fact: if I click cell D32 (has a margin), and then the PaintBrush (to copy the format) and apply it to D34, D34 gets that margin, too!
But without doing that, D34 has no margin.

Here is a link to the example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18lNIA3wBX5EOfvOD2EL5QmLxvKSDslqIfLsFFBWz7rE/edit#gid=0

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=centered - I use American spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused because the format of cells is not unified and can be fixed either with:

- [image: 0] buttons
- or [image: 0] button

Select range **B32:E34** and set it as **Currency**:

[image: 0]

Comment: Making all the relevant fields "Currency" format (and then adjusting the decimals), I got the desired result.